# Аспекты изучения языка

Tags: аспектология

Готовлюсь к экзамену и не понимаю вопрос "Аспекты изучения языка: синхронное и диахронное описание; системно структурный, функционально-семантический, коммуникативно- прагматический и социолингвистический аспекты." Именно сами аспекты: системно структурный, функционально-семантический и т.д.